# Get type of interface property from its string name

Tags: typescript

I have a class `RObject` which takes a generic expected to be an interface type. The interface contains a definition of virtual properties for this object. I want to make properly typed `getProp` and `setProp` methods that consider the schema interface given.

For example, take the following test implementation:

```
interface FooSchema {
  strProp: string;
  numProp: number;
}

const newObj = new RObject<FooSchema>();

newOBj.setProp('strProp', 'some string'); // only allow setting to string since `strProp` is a string in the `FooSchema`.
newOBj.setProp('numProp', 1); // only allow setting to number since `numProp` is a number in the `FooSchema`.
newObj.setProp('numProp', 'bad value'); // this should not be allowed since `numProp` is a number on `FooSchema`.

const strValue: string = newObj.getProp('strProp'); // this is allowed.
const numValue: number = newObj.getProp('strProp'); // this should not be allowed.
```

What I have so far:

```
class RObject<S> {
  public getProp<ValueType extends S[keyof S]>(key: Extract<keyof S, string>): ValueType {
    // ...
  }

  public setProp<ValueType extends S[keyof S]>(key: Extract<keyof S, string>, value: ValueType) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

So far with this, I can get the first `key` parameters to properly enforce that it must be the string name of a key of the schema. But I can't figure out how to get the type of the property that is being get or set. The second parameter of `setProp` is allowing any type, as long as it appears in the schema somewhere. And the `getProp` is allowing a return type of any type in the schema too. How can I restrict the value types to the type of the exact value being operated on?

So basically I need a way to grab the type of the interface property from the string name `key`. Like the ability to do `typeof S[key]`.

Comment: `setProp<K extends keyof S>(key: K, value: S[K]) {...}`

Comment: @AluanHaddad Thank you! You can put that in an answer and I'll accept.

Comment: This works only for getting the string props. You can't simultaneously define the name `getProp` to return a `number` for `'numProp'`. Naming-wise, it would make more sense to call this one `getStringProp` then you could still define a `getNumberProp` that works similarly without conflict.